# Java interface programming

Tags: java, arrays, events, button, interface

I have a problem with the button event. I want to change my array (`dizi[i][j]`) when I press any `btn_ij`. Buttons work well for changing background color, but don't work for array changes (example `dizi[i][j]=2;`). How can I fix this?

```
package renksudokusu;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Sudoku extends JFrame {

public int[][] dizi =
       {{1,2,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1},
        {1,1,1,1}};
public int i,j;

public Sudoku(){

    this.setTitle("asdf");
    this.setSize(600,430);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setResizable(false);

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
            JButton btn_ij=new JButton();
            btn_ij.setBackground(Color.RED);
            this.add(btn_ij);
            btn_ij.setBounds(i*100,j*100,100,100);

            btn_ij.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                if(btn_ij.getBackground()==Color.RED){
                    btn_ij.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    dizi[i][j]=2;
                }

                else if(btn_ij.getBackground()==Color.BLUE){
                    btn_ij.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    dizi[i][j]=3;
                }

                else if(btn_ij.getBackground()==Color.GREEN){
                    btn_ij.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    dizi[i][j]=5;
                }

                else if(btn_ij.getBackground()==Color.YELLOW){
                    btn_ij.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    dizi[i][j]=1;
                }
        }
            });
        }
    }// For döngülerinin bitişi.

    JButton basla=new JButton("Başla");
    this.add(basla);
    basla.setBounds(450,10,100,50);

    JButton kontrol=new JButton("Kontrol Et");
    this.add(kontrol);
    kontrol.setBounds(450,80,100,50);
    kontrol.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<4;j++){

                }
            }
}
    });     

    JButton cikis=new JButton("Çıkış");
    this.add(cikis);
    cikis.setBounds(450,150,100,50);
    cikis.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            System.exit(0);
}
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Sudoku();
}
}
```

Comment: How is "*i want to change my array*" related to your title?

Comment: because i am making java interface program and i have problem when i use ActionListener.

Comment: "Interface programming" doesn't describe problem you are facing. It is like saying "cooking" when you are asking about number of eggs needed to do *something*. Please edit your title and make it more descriptive so people facing same problem could recognize/find your post.

Comment: You did not set a default close operation so when you press x in your sudoku program it keeps running without GUI.
To make it shut down do:
 setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
in the Sudoku constructor.

Comment: Please note: Your indentation is highly inconsistent. Please fix that, both for us and for yourself. Code with indentation all over the place is hard to read, and it is easy to believe code belongs to a different block than it actually belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious bug you have is that `i` and `j` are mutable fields.  You keep changing them as you loop around so that once your loops are finished they will both be `4` which is when the loop stops.  This means all you action listensers will trigger an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException 4 is out of bounds or something like that.

I suggest;

- always read the error message when you get one. It usually gives you a hint as to what the problem is. If you don't understand it, include it int he question.
- The easiest way to diagnose and check this is to debug your program in your debugger.
- don't use fields for loop variables.
- take a `final int finalI = i;` copy of the `i` and use that inside you anonymous inner class.  Note: your IDE should have an autofix for this

Comment: final int finalI = i; this worked for me very well thank you so much <3

Answer (score 1):

i and j go to 4 so you get a array out of bounds exception.
Try like this:

```
        btn_ij.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            int my_i = i;
            int my_j = j;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (btn_ij.getBackground() == Color.RED) {
                    btn_ij.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    System.out.println(my_i);
                    System.out.println(my_j);
                    dizi[my_i][my_j] = 2;
                }

                else if (btn_ij.getBackground() == Color.BLUE) {
                    btn_ij.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    dizi[my_i][my_j] = 3;
                }

                else if (btn_ij.getBackground() == Color.GREEN) {
                    btn_ij.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                    dizi[my_i][my_j] = 5;
                }

                else if (btn_ij.getBackground() == Color.YELLOW) {
                    btn_ij.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    dizi[my_i][my_j] = 1;
                }
            }
        });
```